# Python Script to get List of Software Installed along with Installation date

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script that can extract Software's installed on a windows system along with the date of installation, with little research I managed to extract software information but not sure how I can get the dates, find the script below

```
import subprocess   
  
Data = subprocess.check_output(['wmic', 'product', 'get', 'name'])
a = str(Data) 
  
 
try: 
    
    # arrange the string 
    for i in range(len(a)): 
        print(a.split("\\r\\r\\n")[6:][i]) 
  
except IndexError as e: 
    print("Done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `wmic product get name` does not return the install date, so the first thing we'll need to do is get the install date. `wmic product list` returns more than enough data (there may be a way to limit it further).

From there, we need a way to parse the output. I am using pandas with regex to specify the delimiter as being two or more spaces.

This gives us the following Python code:

```
import io
import subprocess

import pandas as pd


output = subprocess.check_output(["wmic", "product", "list"], text=True)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(output), delimiter='[ ]{2,}', dtype={"InstallDate": "str"})
print(df)
```

Now you have a dataframe with the info, as follows:

```
                                           Description                       IdentifyingNumber InstallDate  ...   SKUNumber    Vendor Version
0                    Python 3.8.5 Executables (64-bit)  {216A8530-DA4B-42FE-BDD4-DCDC1298FB6C}    20200819  ...  3.8.5150.0      None     NaN
1                Python 3.8.5 Utility Scripts (64-bit)  {C28BE172-9103-463D-9793-264434DBDC27}    20200819  ...  3.8.5150.0      None     NaN
2          Python 3.8.5 Development Libraries (64-bit)  {FA7816C5-12FB-4278-9437-E99AA9639E59}    20200819  ...  3.8.5150.0      None     NaN
3                  Python 3.8.5 Documentation (64-bit)  {7211CFF5-CFE7-4B7C-A699-DB0E65DAF4BC}    20200819  ...  3.8.5150.0      None     NaN
4                 Python 3.8.5 Tcl/Tk Support (64-bit)  {B0F29718-AB7A-40AF-8DF9-4E6129FFBCD4}    20200819  ...  3.8.5150.0      None     NaN
..                                                 ...                                     ...         ...  ...         ...       ...     ...
```

Pandas allows pretty easy manipulation; if you wanted a list of the dates, for instance, you could do: `df["InstallDate"].tolist()`

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, but could we use any inbuilt module instead of pandas?